# Unexpected result while sorting using if loops - Bad Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

The objective of my program is to read randomized data of runners and their speeds from a text file and organize it into First, Second and Third. It has their names, bib, age, gender and m:s. However, in this program I cannot use STL/Arrays etc and am limited to ints, doubles and strings.

The code compares the pace of the runners. Here is one of the algorithms I've used

```
int pace_f = 100000;
int pace_s = 100000;
int pace_t = 100000;

if ((pace < pace_t) && (pace > pace_s))
        {
            name_t = name;
            min_t = min;
            sec_t = sec;

            pace_t = pace;
        }

if ((pace < pace_s) && (pace > pace_f))
        {
            name_s = name;
            min_s = min;
            sec_s = sec;

            pace_s = pace;
        }

if (pace < pace_f)
        {
            name_f = name;    
            pace_f = pace;
        }
```

The error is in the output where it displays the First and Second positions correctly. However, it sometimes either fails to print out the third position or provides a wrong one. I understand it does this because it compares the value of the first time that is passed to the loop and since it is always under 10,000 it sets it as the 3rd best time. Now, when a better time comes along, it replaces the one in the third place because it meets all other conditions. The program runs correctly when the first three pace values passed are in ascending order.

So my question is this - How can I correct the error so that it works without needing your numbers to be in ascending order because otherwise this is just pointless.

Comment: For starters, your title refers to "if loops". An `if` statement is not a loop.

Comment: There's no such thing as an if loop.

Comment: Oh I don't know. A few creative `goto`s and you can loop anything! Debug it, maybe not, but it'll loop!

Comment: Not the problem, but `if ((pace < pace_t) && (pace > pace_s))` should be written `if (pace < pace_t && pace > pace_s)`. Redundant parentheses are distracting at best.

Comment: @PeteBecker That seems more like stylistic advice than anything else.  Some people find the parentheses distracting, some people find they make complex conditions easier to parse.

Comment: @JustinTime - the code here does not involve "complex conditions".

Comment: @PeteBecker True.  I was speaking in general, though, not specifically about this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out the logical problem with this part of your existing code:

```
    if (pace < pace_f)
    {
        name_f = name;    
        pace_f = pace;
    }
```

Your other `if` statements have the same problem, but it's easier to explain the problem here, and then you can apply the same fix to all the others.

Here you've decided that your next pace level is better than the current first place finish. Now, it is true that `pace`, the current record, is now the first place pace, and you need to update `name_f` and `pace_f`, the first place records accordingly.

But the detail that you missed is that your current first place pace is now your second best pace, and your current second place pace is now your third best pace.

You just found a record with a pace that's better than your top three paces, so this must mean that your existing best is now the second best, and your existing second best is now your third best.

So, before you can update your first best's pace and name, you need to move your existing second place name and pace to the third place name and pace; your existing first place name and pace to the second place name and pace; and only after that's done, you can update your first place name and pace.

Additionally, you can simply the comparisons by rearranging their relative order with each other.

If you can compare the first place pace first, then the `else` part can then be used to test the remaining possibilities. Once you've excluded the possibility that you have the best first pace, it's simpler to test the remain possibilities.

Your overall logic should be:

```
if (pace < pace_f)
{
     // Move the second place name+pace to third place
     // Move the first place name+pace to the second place
     // Set the new first place pace.
}
else if (pace < pace_s)
{
     // Move the second place name+pace to third place
     // Set the new second place pace.
}
else if (pace < pace_t)
{
     // Set the new third place pace.
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

this is simply done by something like this.
so the idea is when a number better than the first one we should keep the new first and the old first and the second from old data.

```
const int MAX = (int) 1e9; //INT_MAX from <climits> also to be considered
int num1,num2,num3,curr;
string name1,name2,name3,currName;
int main (){
    //the number of data to be entered
    cin>>runnersNum;
    num1=num2=num3=MAX;
    name1=name2=name3="No Name Yet";
    while (runnersNum--){
         cin>>curr>>currName;
         if (curr>=num1){
             if (num3!=MAX&&num2!=MAX) {
             swap(num2,num3); swap(name2,name3);
             swap(num1,num2); swap(name1,name2);
             num1=curr; name1=currName;
             }
         }
         if (curr>=num2){
             swap(num2,num3); swap(name2,name3);
             num2=curr; name2=currName;
         }
         if (curr>=num3){
             num3=curr; name3=currName;
         }
    }
}
```